# Add variables in Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

How to add variables in Crystal Reports from C#. For example I need to add department name and start/finish dates into header of report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass one or more parameters of any datatype from C# to Crystal Report...One can write the code in the page load event.

```
  if (Session["RPT_NAME"] != null)
    {

        ReportDocument rpt = new ReportDocument();
        rpt.Load(Server.MapPath((string)Session["RPT_NAME"]));


        int cnt = rpt.DataDefinition.ParameterFields.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
        {
            ParameterValues myvals = new ParameterValues();
            ParameterDiscreteValue myDiscrete = new ParameterDiscreteValue();

            switch (rpt.DataDefinition.ParameterFields[i].ParameterValueKind)
            {
                case CrystalDecisions.Shared.ParameterValueKind.DateTim eParameter:
                    myDiscrete.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(Request.QueryString[i]);
                    break;

                case CrystalDecisions.Shared.ParameterValueKind.Boolean Parameter:
                    myDiscrete.Value = bool.Parse(Request.QueryString[i]);
                    break;
                case CrystalDecisions.Shared.ParameterValueKind.DatePar ameter:
                    myDiscrete.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(Request.QueryString[i]);
                    break;
                case CrystalDecisions.Shared.ParameterValueKind.NumberP arameter:
                    myDiscrete.Value = int.Parse(Request.QueryString[i]);
                    break;
                case CrystalDecisions.Shared.ParameterValueKind.StringP arameter:
                    myDiscrete.Value = Convert.ToString((Request.QueryString[i]));
                    break;
            }
            myvals.Add(myDiscrete);
            rpt.DataDefinition.ParameterFields[i].ApplyCurrentValues(myvals);
        }
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt;
        CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind();
    }
```